# Объект создается в рандомном месте, хотя я передаю в него определенные координаты

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Всем привет, мне нужно создать объект `failAnim` на определенных координатах, которые я получаю в переменную, по нажатию ЛКМ. Однако объект создается в абсолютно отреченных местах. Я проверял лог, везде пишутся правильные координаты, хотя объект спавнится непонятно где.

```
 public void InstantiateAnimation()
{
    instPref = Instantiate(failAnim, SpritePos, Quaternion.identity);
}

IEnumerator WaitObj()
{
    InstantiateAnimation();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    Debug.Log(SpritePos);
}

private void FindAllMatch(Tile tile)
{
    if (tile.isEmpty)
    {
        return;
    }

    DeleteSprite(tile, new Vector2[2] { Vector2.up, Vector2.down });
    DeleteSprite(tile, new Vector2[2] { Vector2.left, Vector2.right });

    if (isFindMatch)
    {
        isFindMatch = false;

        Debug.Log(IncrementSprite);

        if (tile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite == IncrementSprite)
        {
            ScoreScript.instance.IncreaseScoreCount();
            ScoreScript.instance.ShowScore();
            GameObject tromb = Instantiate(TrombArray[CurrentTromb], TrombArray[CurrentTromb].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            tromb.transform.parent = Canvas.transform;
            CurrentTromb += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(WaitObj());
        }

        tile.spriteRenderer.sprite = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не в тех местах логи ставите. Вам нужно знать SpritePos перед инстанцированием объекта и положение instPref сразу после Instantiate()

Comment: Какое отношение этот код имеет к координате?